# SPARQL* DELETE/INSERT returning error when using nested triples within where clause

Tags: sparql, graphdb, triplestore, rdf-star

why is it not allowed to include a nested triple like `<<?s ?o ?p>> ?x ?y` within the where clause of a insert/delete statement. It immediatelly returns an 500 error.

Following simple statement returns this error.

```
delete {
    
}
insert {
  
                                                           
} where {
<<?s ?o ?p>> ?x ?y.
}
```

Comment: Which version of GraphDB do you use? It can be parsed with Apache Jena, so the query is fine

Comment: I am using GraphDB free

Comment: You are likely hitting a bug in the RDF4J SPARQL engine (which GraphDB partly reuses for SPARQL* support) - see https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/issues/2441 . This was fixed in RDF4J 3.4.0, so you may need to ask for a GraphDB version with that update in.

Comment: Hmm, I think that empty brackets after delete/insert are not legal?